# setInterval inside a return function does not work

Tags: javascript

I have a code similar to the below.

```
function test(){
   return function(){
      setInterval(//Another Function Reference // ,1000);
   }
}
```

I am calling test()();

I see the above code not working. Could someone please explain me why?

Comment: What do you expect it to do?

Comment: There's no closure here.

Comment: The code *before* your edit looked like it would work. The code *after* your edit obviously isn't real code with that comment in it, so how are we to guess what is wrong with your *real* code? At least show that line without a place-holder comment. Do you get any errors in the browser's dev console?

Answer (score 2):

There is no closure in your code<sup>**1**</sup>. `test` returns a function object, but that [function] is not executed. In the snippet, 3 closures are used in the inner function, the returned function object is assigned to a variable, and that is executed. The advantage of returning a function object is that you can assign it to different values and execute them separately.

<sup>**1**</sup> Earlier version of the question mentioned '*closure not working*'

```js
// startInterval: interval 1 second, message: 'Hello' (default)
var startInterval = test(null, 1000);
// anotherInterval: interval 5 seconds, message: ''Hello to you too''
var anotherInterval = test('<i>Hello to you too</i>', 5000);

// execute the function objects
startInterval();            
anotherInterval();

// [hithere], [time] and [result] are closed over
function test(hithere, time){
   hithere = hithere || 'Hello';
   time = time || 1000;
   var result = document.querySelector('#result');
   return function(){
      setInterval(function(){
         result.innerHTML += hithere+'<br>';
      },time || 1000);
   }
}
```

```html
<div id="result">Greetings!<hr></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is working for me... you are returning a function so you will need to invoke this:

http://jsfiddle.net/97hzj2je/

```
function test(){
   return function(){
      setInterval(function(){
         alert("Hello");
      },1000);
   }
}

test()();
```

I assume you are wanting `test()` to be a self invoking function so the return function is set once so instead do:

http://jsfiddle.net/LL24g8z2/

```
var test = (function(){
   return function(){
      setInterval(function(){
         alert("Hello");
      },1000);
   }
})();

test();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function test(){
   return function(){
      setInterval(function(){
         alert("Hello");
      },1000);
   }
}

var hello = test();
hello();
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be working fine. Remember that if you call `test()`, you just get the function back, but you haven't run it. To run it, you need to call the resulting function. You can do this by either:

```
test()();
```

Or:

```
var myFunction = test();
myFunction();
```

Answer (score 0):

`bind` your inner function to the context, the problem is that when the set interval is finally being executed it is in the global scope and not in the one that you called it from. Can be fixed like this:

```
function test(){
   return function(){
      setInterval(/*Another Function Reference */ ,1000);
   }.bind(this)
}
```

Comment: This would not  work: you're trying to call `.bind()` on the return value of `setInterval()`, which is an id not a function.